# Metal Texture mapping on Mac OS with Swift

Tags: swift, graphics, textures, shader, metal

I am following these great Metal tutorials in Swift:

- [Part 1/3](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77488/ios-8-metal-tutorial-swift-getting-started)
- [Part 2/3](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81399/ios-8-metal-tutorial-swift-moving-to-3d)
- [Part 3/3](http://www.raywenderlich.com/93997/ios-8-metal-tutorial-swift-part-3-adding-texture#comments)

Everything works great, until I come to the 3rd part where texture Mapping is explained. Somehow, my mapping gets done very wrong for some faces. There could be many reasons for that, but I am pretty new to Metal, so I believe it's my lack of knowledge and having done something wrong. Anyhow, this is what the outcome looks like:

[image: Distorted texture]

Here I am trying to display two triangles with four vertices (A -> B -> C -> D in counter clockwise order) and somehow the 1st triangle shows a distorted texture (A, B, C) whilst the second looks pretty fine (A, C, D).

In addition to the `Cube` class defined in the tutorials (which shows distorted textures, too) I've made a simpler `Triangle` class to show a square image of a triangle. Yet even for this very simple arrangement, the texture mapping fails.

Rather than showing you the entire code I've appended a [link](http://api.gerfficient.com/Metal%20Test.zip) to my project folder (zip) so you can download and execute the stuff yourselves. I've commented all the code to the best of my abilities and hopefully 
it will make sense to you guys.

Before diving into the few files, I have a rough guess in which file the issue may be:

1. Shader.metal in the `basic_fragment()` function, because it interpolates the colour of the texture to display it in the fragment and the passed coordinates may not be correct.
2. MetalTexture.swift in the `loadTexture()` function, because my fix on how to load a CGImage from an NSImage may be faulty and distort the texture image.
3. Node.swift in the `defaultSampler()` class function, because it is this Metal sampler that is used for interpolation and might be faulty.
4. Everything is correct (*which I doubt*) and it's just Mac OS 10.11 still being in a beta state that causes the problem (*which would be very annoying*)

All in all, I apologise for this wild goose-chaise to find a mistake in my code, but I've been on this for more than a week and am still stuck. Many thanks in advance ;)

**UPDATE # 1**

After loads of experimenting and hacking at it, I managed to map the texture correctly. To do so I followed a peculiar pattern. To explain it easier, here's an image of the corners and the order in which I added them to my Triangle class:

[image: Vertex indexing]

So, the `vertexArray` that is generated therefore consists of the vertices in the following order:

```
[D, B, C, B, D, A]
```

And now to make it even more confusing, here are the vertices' x, y, s and t coordinates:

- `A: (x: -1, y:  1, s: 0, t: 1)`
- `B: (x: -1, y: -1, s: 0, t: 0)`
- `C: (x:  1, y: -1, s: 0, t: 1)`
- `D: (x:  1, y:  1, s: 1, t: 1)`

Whilst the x-y coordinates are ok, the s-r coordinates for `C` and `A` are the same O.o I'm happy I got this simple triangle showing correctly (image as proof below) but I wouldn't know where to start debugging for anything larger.

To make it even more annoying, when changing the order of the two faces, so it says

```
[B, D, A, D, B, C]
```

instead of

```
[D, B, C, B, D, A]
```

everything gets mis-mapped again, despite the information being the same. Any clue why guys?

[image: Fixed image]

**Update # 2**

Turns out it's still not fixed, especially when adding animations to the bunch. There are some horrible mis-mapped textures when the image that looks so pretty up there is rotated. Now I'm starting to fear if this is a driver issue. I'm running of an Nvidia card, not AMD...

[image: Artifacts or what is it]

Comment: I opened and ran your project. Are we supposed to do something to get an incorrect render? It looks fine to me. Please let us know what exactly we must fix. It's possible that it just doesn't work for your GPU; what are you using? I've got the AMD Radeon R9 M370X.

Comment: I have an Nvidia GT 750M (MacBook Pro 2014) so maybe it's a driver issue?

For now, I tweaked the values and fixed it for my triangle now (after loads of experimenting). But it seems counterintuitive and the cube will be a different nightmare :/ I'll update the question...

Comment: I have also confronted with that recently.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in the shader compiler backend specific to the Nvidia 750M. Using the Intel graphics card or using a workaround in the shader code fixes the issue.

You can find a full writeup and Xcode project [here](http://recoursive.com/2016/01/22/metal_shader_bug/).

Specifically, the problem is the VertexIn struct.

```
struct VertexIn {
    packed_float3 position;
    packed_float4 color;
    packed_float2 texCoord;
};
```

The packed_float3 will lead to the compiler generating invalid offsets for the texCoord member. If you change it to a packed_float4 (pass 1.0f as the 4th float), the textures will be rendered correctly.